# how to set different color of solid property for different styles in drawable.xml in android?

Tags: android, styles, drawable

i have problem and i really search a lot  and wasted big time,

my problem is i have 2 style , one style for each activity and it's child with of course different (colorPrimary and colorPrimaryDark), this is the 2 styles :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="adapter_button_color">@color/secondary_orange</item>
</style>

 <style name="AppTheme.SurveyStyle" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary2</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark2</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent2</item>

    <item name="adapter_button_color">@color/button_click</item>
</style>
```

, and i have drawable names raised_selector using as background for buttons

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/raised_pressed"/><!-- pressed -->
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/raised_normal" /> <!-- default -->
```

and the code of raised_normal for example :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />

<stroke
    android:width="3dp"
    android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />

<padding
    android:bottom="1dp"
    android:left="1dp"
    android:right="1dp"
    android:top="1dp" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="3dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="3dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="3dp"
    android:topRightRadius="3dp" />
```

when i set  `<solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />` like that the color of button in different styles will be the same , so i search and find if i write 
`<solid android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" />` instead will get the primerycolor of the style .

is it fine for now !! so every think work ok using  (?attr/colorPrimary) work ok but this in v-21 and above and minimum sdks if i set  (?attr/colorPrimary) instead of "@color/colorPrimary" the application will crash .

so what i can do in this way and set the color depend on the style ?
thanks for your time and thanks for reading

Comment: any body can help me , will be very thankful

Answer (score 0):

This mean there is no solution for this problem in the older phone :(